# Logstash with Filebeat error: Could not execute action

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

Hi Im trying to set up a log analysis with Filebeat and Logstash.
Below are the changes i made in

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\elasticsearch-5.4.3\elasticsearch-5.4.3\logs\elasticsearch.log

output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

And here is my logstash configuration file.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{plugins}" }
    }
    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-DD:HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
}
```

While running the above, i see the below error:

```
[2019-10-22T06:07:32,915][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline aborted due
 to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{plu
gins} not defined>, :backtrace=>["D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/vendor/bundle
/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:123:in `block in compile'", "
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1425:in `loop'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/ven
dor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:93:in `compile'", "
D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-
grok-4.0.4/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:281:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/
RubyArray.java:1792:in `each'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/vendor/bundle/
jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.0.4/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:275:in
`block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1419:in `each'", "D:/logstash-7.1
.0/logstash-7.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.0.4/lib/
logstash/filters/grok.rb:270:in `register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/Ab
stractFilterDelegatorExt.java:56:in `register'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1
.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:191:in `block in register_plugins
'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1792:in `each'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0
/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:190:in `register_plugins'", "D:/log
stash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:446:in `m
aybe_setup_out_plugins'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/lo
gstash/java_pipeline.rb:203:in `start_workers'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1
.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:145:in `run'", "D:/logstash-7.1.0
/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:104:in `block in sta
rt'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x15997940 run>"}
[2019-10-22T06:07:32,970][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute ac
tion {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message
=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false"
, :backtrace=>nil}
```

Im rather new to this intergration, im not sure of where i should look into.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks to be with

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{plugins}" }
}
```

What is `%{plugins}` here? It is NOT a pre-defined `grok` pattern. The list of `grok` patterns can be found [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Also, the syntax for a `grok` pattern from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) is `%{SYNTAX:SEMANTIC}`. You could do something like

```
grok {
  match => { "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:plugins}" }
}
```

Comment: Plugin is actually an existing word on the logfile, should i still use it as `"%{GREEDYDATA:plugins}"` ? I tried the above, but i cannot see the index being created in the Elasticsearch. Logstash shows `[2019-10-22T12:06:33,120][INFO ][logstash.agent] Successfully starte
 Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}` and no change execution after. I ran, `logstash -f myfile.conf` in the cmd as admin. @SandeepKanabar

Comment: What `"%{GREEDYDATA:plugins}"` means is that your entire message will be collected into `plugins` field which will then get indexed into ES.

Try running logstash with `--debug` option i.e. `logstash --debug -f my file.conf`. Also, since you have NOT specified index name in `output { elasticsearch { ..} }`, indexing will happen by default to `logstash-yyyy.mm.dd` index where `yyyy.mm.dd` reflects today's UTC date. 

Before running logstash, do `GET _cat/indices` and after running again run the same command to know if any index was created or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving data type of the `"%{plugins}"`.

```
filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{WORD:plugins}" }
    }
}
```

You can find data types from [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-basic-grok-field-types-description/109690)

If this not working try removing date filter and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently these kind of errors can happen because of some regexp syntax error deep into a config file. That's just crack.